# Am I using the Bernoulli formula correctly?

Tags: probability

Can you please explain the formula if it's wrong and if I am using the correctly...

An oil company estimates that only $1$ well in $16$ will yield commercial quantities of oil. Assume that successful drilled wells represent independent events. If $12$ wells are drilled, find the probability of obtaining a commercially successful well for the following number of times exactly $4$.

$${\binom{12}{4}\frac1{16^4}\frac1{16^8}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite

$$P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k \color{blue}{(1-p)}^{n-k}$$

You did not apply the colored part correctly.